# .NET Core project looking for deleted packages?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a .NET core project and had to remove a nuget package due to licensing issues.
I made sure to remove it from the .csproj file as well yet still when i try to build the solution i get this.

[image]

Why is it still looking for it and how do I make it stop?

Comment: try clean/rebuild/restart vs. also you can use other editors(such as vscode) to search for the keyword, maybe somewhere else should be removed.

Comment: i tried all of this, nothing works

Comment: please commit the project to github. i don't believe anyone else can reproduce.

Comment: i cant do that as it is company code ;(

Comment: then you cannot get answers as well.

Comment: Check the references. Sometimes the reference still exists while you uninstalled the nuget package.

Comment: The references in the csproj file or ?

Comment: it says its missing in line 1 of the .csproj file but line 1 says : <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

Comment: Try cloning the project again. Try going to an older commit. Try clearing the nuget cache. Check if other colleagues also have the problem. Take a look at the verbose logs from dotnet build/restore logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that there were nuget packages (dependencies) that used the package.

Answer (score 1):

There may be indirect dependencies - some other NuGet package in your code depends on the package you removed.

In Visual Studio or Rider you can expand the NuGet dependencies note in your Solution Explorer to see each packages indirect dependencies.

To quickly search among all dependencies, you can open the `obj/project.assets.json` file. All direct and indirect dependencies are stored there. You can search that file to see if the package is referenced indirectly.

For example, this snippet shows that using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.0 in a project adds indirect dependencies to Azure.Core and Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, because `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` supports Azure AD authentication

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "targets": {
    "net6.0": {
      "Azure.Core/1.6.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces": "1.0.0",
          "System.Buffers": "4.5.0",
          "System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource": "4.6.0",
          "System.Memory": "4.5.3",
          "System.Numerics.Vectors": "4.5.0",
          "System.Text.Json": "4.6.0",
          "System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions": "4.5.2"
        },
        "compile": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Azure.Core.dll": {}
        },
        "runtime": {
          "lib/netstandard2.0/Azure.Core.dll": {}
        }
      },
....
      "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient/4.0.0": {
        "type": "package",
        "dependencies": {
          "Azure.Identity": "1.3.0",
          "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.runtime": "4.0.0",
          "Microsoft.Identity.Client": "4.22.0",
          "Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens": "6.8.0",
          "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect": "6.8.0",
          "Microsoft.Win32.Registry": "5.0.0",
...
```

Comment: Yes this is what i did and then i removed the dependencies from those packages as well.